# Which type of Android widget Google+ and Facebook use for their feeds?

Tags: android, facebook, listview, google-plus

Does anyone know which widget do these applications use for their feeds? It looks like a custom `ListView` and `HTML` blending together. I wonder how can we make something similar to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really interesting question. They use custom list items, and the most interesting part is TextView with links  working. Here is what I have found:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Those two lines of code, will make links(`<a>` tags) in TextView clickable.
They probably also use  this method: http://goo.gl/zLWgA - to set custom link background changes when user click the link.